# How can I make these two buttons have the same width?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want the login and register buttons to have the same width. I want it to be done using flex or anything similar but do not hardcode the pixels amount.

This is my current JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/akap9dq0/.

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">...</a>
        <button aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed navbar-toggle" data-target="#main_menu" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
          <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_menu">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" style="border: none;">
          <div id="main_menu_container">
            <div id="main_menu_form_input">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name" style="flex:1;">
              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="flex:1;">
            </div>
            <div id="main_menu_form_buttons">
              <input class="btn btn-block btn-success" type="submit" style="flex: 1; margin: 0;" value="login">
              <input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" style="flex: 1; margin: 0;" value="register">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's preventing you from just setting the width?

Comment: @jhpratt what if in the future one of the button texts must change? You souldnt be having to modify hard coded CSS values every time you change button text.

Comment: @jhpratt using Flex it will certainly be possible

Comment: Well I posted a working CSS only solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you are looking for with the following CSS:

```
.control-panel {
  display: inline;
}

.control-panel__btn {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.control-panel__btn .btn {
  width: 100%;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="control-panel">
    <div class="control-panel__btn">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="signinup" value="Sign In">
    </div>
    <div class="control-panel__btn">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="signinup" value="Sign Up">
    </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akap9dq0/6/

Comment: Thanks, I use your solution. CSS is just a black magic fuckery for me. I am not sure why you need to use `table-cell` right there. But it works so I will not complain further XD.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

wrap buttons in useflex class

```
<div class="useflex">
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="signinup" value="Sign In">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="signinup" value="Sign Up">
</div>
```

and apply this style:

```
.useflex{
  display: inline-flex;

  max-width:200px;
}

.useflex .btn{
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to add css elements

```
 .btn-success{
 width:100px;
}
.btn-primary{
 width:100px;
}
```

This will do...

Comment: oopsi didn't see that. but he have to set the width right??

Comment: OP is looking for a solution that does not involve setting the width.

Comment: well how to do that??

Comment: See my posted answer.

Comment: what is the merit (pros) in the code that u have written

Comment: It solve's OP's problem of having the buttons be the same width without hard coding the values?

Comment: oh so he didn't have to change the button's values .

Comment: I'm curious who declined my flag as not an answer. This is completely wrong, as the question explicitly states without using preset widths.

Comment: are you thinking its me?, if yes then you are wrong coz i dont even understand what hard coding values mean thats why i stayed silent and i dont even know what the answer is ...

Comment: and what is flag declining i am new to this side of stackoverflow

Comment: @jhpratt Unfortunately flagging because it's an incorrect answer is not within the scope of flags. The only thing you can do is downvote and leave a comment warning that this answer is incorrect, such as what you have done.  FWIW, I did not decline your flag.

Comment: @rayryeng I flagged it not because it was in correct, but because it completely ignored a requirement ─ which in my opinion isn't answering the question. I've learned that I can't flag it because it's incorrect (the hard way, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Set size based on text `display: inline-block;`

or otherway is to give a `%` to the width of it.

```css
.btn {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display. -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed navbar-toggle" data-target="#main_menu" data-toggle="collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_menu">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" style="border: none; padding: 0;">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name">
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="signinup" value="Sign In">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="signinup" value="Sign Up">
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already using bootstrap, so adding these bootstrap classes to your html elements will do all that you are asking:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right row" style="border: none; padding: 0;">         
    <input class="form-control col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3" type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name">         
    <input class="form-control col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input class="btn btn-success col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 sm" type="submit" name="signinup" value="Sign In0000">
    <input class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 sm" type="submit" name="signinup" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

You will need to add these classes too:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
.sm{
    width: 20%;
}}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-form .form-control{
    width: 30%;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are requiring a flexible way to make both buttons in same width, you may need JQuery to help you. Here you are.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
          var success = $(".btn-success");
          var primary = $(".btn-primary");
          var success_width = success.outerWidth();
          var primary_width = primary.outerWidth();
          var both_width;
          

          if( success_width > primary_width || success_width == primary_width ){
              both_width = success_width;
          }else if( primary_width > success_width){
              both_width = primary_width;
          }
          
          success.css({
              width: both_width + "px"
          });
          primary.css({
              width: both_width + "px"
          });
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    

    <script type="text/javascript">
       

    </script>

</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display. -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed navbar-toggle" data-target="#main_menu" data-toggle="collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_menu">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" style="border: none; padding: 0;">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name">
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="signinup" value="Sign In" id="btn-success">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="signinup" value="whynot longer" id="btn-primary">
          <span id="result">&nbsp;</span>
        </form>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope you can find your way!

Answer (score -2):

Just add custom class to these buttons and set the width.

Like

```
.custom-btn{
  width: 100px;
}
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/akap9dq0/1/)

Comment: sry i didn't look at it